# Target vuejs app outside of its wrapper

Tags: javascript, methods, vue.js

I am using [vue.js](http://vuejs.org) for a small web app. The whole content is wrapped in a `div#app`. How can I trigger a function outside of `#app`?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'I am a working vue app'
  },
  methods: { 
    showAlert: function() {
      alert("Hello world");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
    <button v-on:click="showAlert">Alert</button>
  </div>
  
  <button v-on:click="showAlert">Alert not working</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that it's bad practice. But you can always add id="app" to body (which is not recommended too)

Comment: @Filip why do you think it's bad practice?

Comment: @BertEvans vue gave me a warning when I tried to add it to the body the first time.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal add what?

Comment: @BertEvans sorry, I meant adding vuejs to `body` instead of a `div#app`

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I understand you now. I was referring to "You shouldn't do that it's bad practice". I agree, I don't think you should try to use `body` as your template.

Comment: @BertEvans It was an experiment that I did the first time I wanted to try and I got a nice warning telling me not to do so. I tried to find a reason but there is this "it is not recommended" thing I get everytime.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal The reasons you don't render to `body` are the essentially the same as described here for React in the "Don't Render To Body" section. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the alert is not going to work because Vue is only going to do anything with the code inside it's template. You've identified the template as `#app`, so the only HTML that Vue is concerned with is

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <button v-on:click="showAlert">Alert</button>
</div>
```

That being the case, you've defined a *Vue specific* means of attaching an event handler to code elsewhere in your HTML.

```
<button v-on:click="showAlert">Alert not working</button>
```

The reason it doesn't work is because Vue doesn't even know that code exists. It is not inside `#app`.

If you wanted to trigger the alert from outside, you can use any plain javascript method for attaching an event handler to your button and call the method. For example,

```
<button onclick="app.showAlert()">Alert not working</button>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/QvLQNG?editors=1010).

Note: You probably shouldn't set both the `id` and the variable that captures the result of `new Vue()` to the same name, `app`. In most browsers, the `id` of HTML elements are exposed in the global scope and you now have two variables named `app`. In this case, the Vue wins, but you can easily change it to something like

```
var myApp = new Vue({...})
```

to spare confusion. If you did that, the line above would be

```
<button onclick="myApp.showAlert()">Alert not working</button>
```